# vue: dependency not found after running npm install --save

Tags: vue.js, dependencies, npm-install, adminlte

I'm trying to customize [CoPilot](https://github.com/misterGF/CoPilot) (a vue admin template based on [AdminLTE](https://github.com/almasaeed2010/AdminLTE)).

I want to add support for [morris.js](http://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/) graphics library.

So in Dashboard.vue I try to add the following:

```
<script>
import Chart from 'chart.js'
import Morris from 'morris.js'   // added line!
import Alert from '../widgets/Alert'
```

And when I run `npm run dev` I get the following error:

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors
This dependency was not found:
* morris.js in ./~/babel-loader/lib!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/components/views/Dashboard.vue
To install it, you can run: npm install --save morris.js
```

I issue `npm install --save morris.js`, I can see that it gets added to my package.json

```
"jquery": "^2.2.2",
"moment": "^2.12.0",
"morris.js": "^0.5.0",
"vue": "^2.2.2",
"vue-date-picker": "^1.0.2",
```

but the message keeps popping up.

Am I missing anything? Is there some npm command to force to download every dependency?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding below code in your webpack file??

webpack.config.js

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.common.js',
      'jquery': 'jquery/src/jquery.js'
    }
  },
```